# Left and Right minimal homomorphisms.

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory, homological-algebra

In the literature on representation theory of finite dimensional algebras, a left (and similarly right) minimal homomorphism is defined as the following:

For a pair of modules $L $ and $M$ in $mod-A$, an $A-$homomorphism $f:L\rightarrow M$ is called left minimal if for every $h\in End(M)$, if $h\circ f = f$, then $h\in Aut(M)$.

Here are my questions:

- Since for any arbitrary module $X$ in $mod-A$, we can consider the set of all pairs ($Y, f)$, where $f:Y\rightarrow X$ is a left minimal homomorphism, and this set is always nonempty (it at least contains $(X,1_X)$ ), could we possibly use inclusion as a partial order and talk about the smallest $(Y,f)$, which may not be necessarily unique, as the best object with such a property? Moreover, if two objects themselves are not comparable (with regard to the partial order defined by inclusion) their images in $X$ might be. So, we could possibly compare the images as well and talk about something like "best left minimal homomorphism(s) for a given module $X$ in $mod-A$".

Does it make sense at all to think about such a notion?

- So far, I have seen the aforementioned notions (Left and right minimal homomorphisms) only in the literature of representation of finite dimensional algebras. But, at least at this step, the definitions seem to be independent of the good properties that this category possesses. Could one study these type of morphisms in any other category (at least abelian categories). If so, which seems to be plausible, I was wondering if you could let me know why they only (as long as I know) appear in this area.

I already know that they are used to firstly define left and right minimal almost split morphisms and consequently almost split sequences, which lead to the proof of the first Brauer_Thrall Conjecture. But, I am curious to know if they also have other applications in other areas.

Comment: For your first question, (if I am not mistaken) that was exactly Auslander was trying to play with.  It's called "morphisms determined by module".  I don't know much about this, but Ringel and XiaoWu Chen are looking into this very recently; and some people are generalising to other categories too. Search those keywords on arXiv/google will give you something.  Sorry that I know too few to answer your question properly.

Comment: Almost split sequences are used for much, much, much more than proving the first Brauer-Thrall conjecture! Pick, for example, The book by Skowronski, Assem and Simpson: its three volumes of (increasingly elaborate and hard!) results obtained from working with A-R sequences, and they only deal with the simplest results in the literature...

Comment: (and they give a proof of 1st Brauer-Thrall already after the first few 50 pages or so)

Comment: I think one is usually interested in these in combination with some other property. For example: Consider an $R$-module $M$ and all embeddings $M \hookrightarrow E$, where $E$ is some injective module. Then among these, the left minimal ones are precisely embeddings into (some isomorphic copy of) injective hull of $M$. The same goes for epimorphisms $P \twoheadrightarrow M$, where $P$ is projective (flat): right minimal ones are precisely projective (flat) covers. In fact, there is a general approximation theory which studies such envolopes/covers by suitable classes of modules.

Comment: Dear Aaron, Thanks for your comment on the first question and informing me of the current attempts.

Comment: Dear Mariano, Actually I am reading the same book and the questions came to my mind once I could not find any comments on the possible generalization(s) of these morphisms. I might need to be patient and read more to get to what you mentioned- much much much more.

Comment: Dear PavelC, Do we really need to limit ourselves to the category of modules to talk about these properties, or could we possibly think about any abelian category?

Comment: @Kaveh: I think these notions are possible to define in any Abelian category (cf. Enochs, Jenda: Relative homological algebra, chapter 8). The comment was meant mostly as an example in which context the minimal homomorphisms appear as well.

Comment: To partially answer your question to PavelC: No, in fact, minimality, almost splitness, these kinds of stuff are very useful for studying homological algebra, where we work with triangulated categories rather than abelian category.  In fact, we usually just look at additive subcategory of some "good" category (abelian/triangulated or similar things), then tweak the original definitions.